# Equalizing the length of several springs and dampers

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've tried to standardize several springs and dampers from the picture with the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphics,epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{
      spring/.style={thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}},
      blank/.style={draw=none,fill=none,pos=0.5},
      ground/.style={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm},
      damper/.style={thick,
         decoration={markings, mark connection node=dmp,
           mark=at position 0.5 with
          {
            \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=10pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,3pt)$);
          }
          }, decorate
      }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
      \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
        \node (M) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[blank,below=0.5] {$d_1$};
        %\draw [<-,thick](-2.6,.6) -- (-1.5,-.2);
        \node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
        \draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
        \draw [spring] (wall.120) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.120)!(M.south west)$) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_1$};
    \draw [damper] (wall.20) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.20)!(M.south west)$);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
    \node (M1) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[blank,below=0.5] {$d_2$};
    \draw [spring] (M.10) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.10)!(M1.south west)$) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_2$};
    \draw [damper] (M.-40) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.-40)!(M1.south west)$);
  \end{scope}

   \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
    \node (S) [blank,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$\cdots$} node[blank,below=0.225] {$\cdots$};
   \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[xshift=11cm]
    \draw [spring] (M1.10) -- ($(S.north west)!(M1.10)!(S.south west)$) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_3$};
    \draw [damper] (M1.-40) -- ($(S.north west)!(M1.-40)!(S.south west)$);
      \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[xshift=14cm]
    \node (M2) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[blank,below=0.5] {$d_{n-1}$}; 
    \draw [spring] (S.10) -- ($(M2.north west)!(S.10)!(M2.south west)$) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_{n-1}$};
    \draw [damper] (S.-40) -- ($(M2.north west)!(S.-40)!(M2.south west)$);
  \end{scope} 

\begin{scope}[xshift=16cm]
    \node (M3) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[blank,below=0.5] {$d_n$};
    \draw [spring] (M2.10) -- ($(M3.north west)!(M1.10)!(M3.south west)$) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_n$};
    \draw [damper] (M2.-40) -- ($(M3.north west)!(M1.-40)!(M3.south west)$);
  \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[xshift=17cm]
   \node[] (wall1) [ground, rotate=90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
  \draw (wall1.north west) -- (wall1.north east);
   \draw [spring] (wall1.60) -- ($(M3.north east)!(wall1.60)!(M3.south east)$) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_1$};
   \draw [damper] (wall1.160) -- ($(M3.north east)!(wall1.-160)!(M3.south east)$);
 \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

I need help to bring all springs and dampers at the same length.

[image]

Comment: An option is to use the `positioning library`. So you could use `right= 2cm of wall` ... . `\node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2cm] {};\node[right= 1.2cm of wall,yshift=1cm] (M1) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[draw=none,below = 0.2cm of M1] {$d_1$};` etc... .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the syntax of the `positioning` library as Bobyandbob suggested is a good idea, but don't set the distance explicitly for each node, set it once as `node distance`. I also changed some other things, such as using perpendicular coordinates (`(a -| b)`) for the dampers, and I used a `label` to add the `d_N` nodes.

I also defined a `box` style for the `m` nodes.

Unrelated note: Of `graphics,epsfig,graphicx` you need only load `graphicx`. It loads `graphics` already, and `epsfig` is just a wrapper around `graphicx` these days anyway I believe, so  there is no need for it. But `tikz` loads `graphicx` anyway, so strictly speaking you can remove that entire `\usepackage` call.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
   decorations.markings,
   decorations.pathmorphing,
   calc,
   patterns,
   positioning
}

\tikzset{
      spring/.style={thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}},
      blank/.style={draw=none,fill=none,pos=0.5},
      ground/.style={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm},
      damper/.style={thick,
         decoration={markings, mark connection node=dmp,
           mark=at position 0.5 with
          {
            \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=10pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,3pt)$);
          }
          }, decorate
      },
     box/.style={draw,thick,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm}
    }


\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
   % modify this to set distance between nodes
   node distance=1.2cm
]
        \node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2cm] {};
        \node (M1) [box, right=of wall.north,label=below:$d_1$] {$m$};
        \node (M2) [box,right=of M1,label=below:$d_2$] {$m$};


        \draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
        \draw [spring] (wall.north) -- (M1) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_1$};
        \draw [damper] (wall.20) -- (wall.20 -| M1.west) coordinate (d1);

        \draw [spring] (M1) -- (M2) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_2$};
        \draw [damper] (d1-|M1.east) -- (d1 -| M2.west);

        \coordinate [right=of M2] (k3);
        \draw [spring] (M2) -- (k3) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_3$};
        \draw [damper] (d1-|M2.east) -- (d1 -| k3) coordinate (d3);

        \coordinate [right=1cm of k3] (k4);

        \node (M3) [box,right=of k4,label=below:$d_{n-1}$] {$m$};
        \draw [spring] (k4) -- (M3) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_{n-1}$};
        \draw [damper] (d1-|k4) -- (d1 -| M3.west);

        \node (M4) [box,right=of M3,label=below:$d_{n}$] {$m$};
        \draw [spring] (M3) -- (M4) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_{n}$};
        \draw [damper] (d1-|M3.east) -- (d1 -| M4.west);

        \node (wall2) [ground, right=of M4, anchor=north,rotate=90,minimum width=2cm] {};
        \draw [spring] (M4) -- (wall2) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {$k_{1}$};
        \draw [damper] (d1-|M4.east) -- (d1 -| wall2.north);


      \path (k3) -- node[draw=none]{$\cdots$} (k4);
      \path (d3) -- node[draw=none]{$\cdots$} (d3-|k4);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Second version

Below follows a second version of the code. I'm adding this separately, because I've modified most styles somewhat. For example, node names are added as arguments to styles, instead of `(nodename)` outside node options, for both `box` and `ground` I've specified `node contents`, so that the `{text}` is not needed. Whether you think this is better or worse is for you to decide, I'm adding it for fun, and to introduce more of TikZ' options. 
I also used a loop to draw all the springs and dampers, which shortens the code a bit.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
   decorations.markings,
   decorations.pathmorphing,
   calc,
   patterns,
   positioning
}

\tikzset{
   spring/.style={
     thick,
     decorate,
     decoration={
         zigzag,
         pre length=0.3cm,
         post length=0.3cm,
         segment length=6
     }
   },
   ground/.style={
      fill,
      pattern=north east lines,
      draw=none,
      minimum width=0.3cm, % height > width,
      minimum height=2cm,  % instead of rotating
      name=#1,
      node contents={}
   },
   damper/.style={
      thick,
      decoration={
         markings,
         mark connection node=dmp,
         mark=at position 0.5 with
            {
             % as for the wall, swap width and height to make it clearer what the drawing does
             \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=3pt,minimum height=10pt,draw=none] {};
             \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -| (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.south east)+(2pt,0)$);
             \draw [thick] ($(dmp.east)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(dmp.east)+(0,3pt)$);
            }
         },
      decorate
      },
   box/.style 2 args={
     % style 2 args means use as box={a}{b}
     % both arguments are mandatory
     draw,thick,
     minimum width=1cm,
     minimum height=1cm,
     name=#1, % #1 refers to first argument, #2 to second
     label=below:$d_{#2}$, 
     node contents={$m$}
   },
   k-nodes/.style={
       midway,
       above=1.5mm
   }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   % modify this to set distance between nodes (i.e. length of springs/dampers
   node distance=1.1cm
]

        % first set up nodes
        \node [ground=wall];
        \coordinate (ds) at ($(wall.east)!4mm!(wall.south east)$); % starting point for dampers
        \node [box={M1}{1}, right=of wall];
        \node [box={M2}{2}, right=of M1];
        \coordinate [right=of M2] (k3);     % end point of k3 spring
        \coordinate [right=1cm of k3] (k4); % start point of k4 spring
        \coordinate (d3) at (ds -| k3);     % end point of third damper
        \node [box={M3}{n-1}, right=of k4];
        \node [box={M4}{n},   right=of M3];
        \node [ground=wall2,  right=of M4];

        % draw sides of walls
        \draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.south east);
        \draw (wall2.north west) -- (wall2.south west);

        % draw all springs and dampers
        \foreach \A/\B/\N in {
            wall/M1/k_1,
            M1/M2/k_2,
            M2/k3/k_3,
            k4/M3/k_{n-1},
            M3/M4/k_n,
            M4/wall2/k_1}
        {
           \draw [spring] (\A) -- (\B) node[k-nodes] {$\N$};
           \draw [damper] (ds -| \A.east) -- (ds -| \B.west);
        }

      % add dots in the middle
      \path (k3) -- node {$\cdots$} (k4);
      \path (d3) -- node {$\cdots$} (d3-|k4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why in the first version the right `wall2` doesn't have a vertical line before the hatching, like the left `wall` does ?

Comment: @Cris That line is drawn by `\draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);` and a corresponding line for `wall2` is missing.