# Drawing a horizontal damper in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need help in order to straighten the skew damper connecting the south east of the mass `M1` to the south west of the `wall1`:

[image]

I tried several times unsuccessfully to change the coordinates. How could I fix this ? My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphics,epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\tikzset{
      spring/.style={thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}},
      blank/.style={draw=none,fill=none,pos=0.5},
      ground/.style={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm},
      damper/.style={thick,
         decoration={markings, mark connection node=dmp,
           mark=at position 0.5 with
          {
            \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=10pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,3pt)$);
          }
          }, decorate
      }
    }
\par
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
      \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
        \node (M) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$M$};
        %\draw [<-,thick](-2.6,.6) -- (-1.5,-.2);
        \node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
        \draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
        \draw [spring] (wall.120) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.120)!(M.south west)$) ;
    \draw [damper] (wall.20) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.20)!(M.south west)$);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=10.3cm]
    \node (M1) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$M_{1}$} ;
    \draw [spring] (M.10) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.10)!(M1.south west)$);
    \draw [damper] (M.-40) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.-40)!(M1.south west)$);
   %\draw [->,thick](1.4,-.2) -- (2.5,.6);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=10.3cm]
    \node[] (wall1) [ground, rotate=90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
    \draw (wall1.north west) -- (wall1.north east);
    \draw [spring] (wall1.60) -- ($(M1.north east)!(wall1.60)!(M1.south east)$);
    \draw [damper] (M1.-40) -- ($(wall1.north west)!0!(wall1.south west)$);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `(M1.-40 -| wall1.north)`. I kind of told you about this in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399674/equalizing-the-length-of-several-springs-and-dampers/400582#400582 ...

Comment: Indeed, I forgot your method.  It's easier and efficient. Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi I just modified the last damper plot command  `\draw [damper] (M1.-40) -| (M1.-40-|wall1.60);`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphics,epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\tikzset{
      spring/.style={thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}},
      blank/.style={draw=none,fill=none,pos=0.5},
      ground/.style={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm},
      damper/.style={thick,
         decoration={markings, mark connection node=dmp,
           mark=at position 0.5 with
          {
            \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=10pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,3pt)$);
          }
          }, decorate
      }
    }
\par
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
      \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
        \node (M) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$M$};
        %\draw [<-,thick](-2.6,.6) -- (-1.5,-.2);
        \node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
        \draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
        \draw [spring] (wall.120) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.120)!(M.south west)$) ;
    \draw [damper] (wall.20) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.20)!(M.south west)$);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=10.3cm]
    \node (M1) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$M_{1}$} ;
    \draw [spring] (M.10) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.10)!(M1.south west)$);
    \draw [damper] (M.-40) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.-40)!(M1.south west)$);
   %\draw [->,thick](1.4,-.2) -- (2.5,.6);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=10.3cm]
    \node[] (wall1) [ground, rotate=90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
    \draw (wall1.north west) -- (wall1.north east);
    \draw [spring] (wall1.60) -- ($(M1.north east)!(wall1.60)!(M1.south east)$);
    \draw [damper] (M1.-40) -| (M1.-40-|wall1.60);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]